# Scala spark can't access tuple after flatmap with yield

Tags: scala, apache-spark, tuples, yield, flatmap

```
    val test_rated = pearson.flatMap(x => {
        val bid1 = x._1._1.toInt
        val bid2 = x._1._2.toInt
        val sim = x._2.toDouble

        val pairs = for (tu <- test_users) yield {
            val tid = tu.toInt
            if (test_map.contains((tid, bid2)) && train_map.contains((tid, bid1))){
                ((tid, bid2), (bid1, sim))
            }
        }
        pairs
    }).filter(row => row!= ())
```

In this code block `test_users` is a scala `list`. After the `flatMap` operation with yield I was able to get the result and print it with `foreach`.
However, if I want to map it again like

```
test_rated.map(x => x._2)
```

I couldn't access each individual tuple values by using `x._2`

Comment: Can you provide your sample data of  `pearson, test_users, test_map and train_map` ?

Comment: `pearson` is a rdd with each row as `((bid1, bid2), sim)`

`test_users` is a scala 1D List
test_map and train_map shouldn't matter in this case since it's only used for the condition statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the rest of the code is correct and types match (impossible to say without a [mcve])) you're just doing this a wrong way. Let's simplify the process to show why:

```
scala> for {
     | x <- 1 to 5
     | } yield { if (x % 2 == 0) x}
res0: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[AnyVal] = Vector((), 2, (), 4, ())
```

As you see the type is not `Seq[Int]` but `Seq[AnyVal]`. Filtering the data won't change that:

```
scala> res0.filter(x => x != ())
res1: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[AnyVal] = Vector(2, 4)
```

You could `collect`:

```
scala> res0.collect { case x: Int => x}
res2: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(2, 4)
```

but really you should use guarding expression:

```
scala> for {
     | x <- 1 to 5 if x % 2 == 0
     | } yield x
res3: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(2, 4)
```

so your code should be rewritten as:

```
val test_rated = pearson.flatMap(x => {
    val bid1 = x._1._1.toInt
    val bid2 = x._1._2.toInt
    val sim = x._2.toDouble

    def keep(tid) = {
      test_map.contains((tid, bid2)) && train_map.contains((tid, bid1))
    }

    for {
      tid <- test_users.map(_.toInt) if keep(tid)
    } yield ((tid, bid2), (bid1, sim))
})
```

Comment: That works thanks a lot! A little follow up, if say none of the items met the condition in for loop, what would yield return?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the code block within `flatMap()` is not evaluating to any object. You should either remove `val pairs =` or explicitly return `pairs` -- such as

```
pearson.flatMap(x => { 
  ... 
  val pairs = ...
  pairs
}).filter(...)
```

Comment: I did explicitly return pairs sorry my bad I've included the wrong code. Explicitly return pairs as the format above still doesn't let me access the tuples in a map operation after like `x._2`